# Is user based cache cleared when flush all cache is used in drupal 7?

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 7, when we click flush all cache, is User based cache also cleared?

Comment: Yes, user cache is also cleared but only from the database, not from client side browser.

Comment: Thanks @ViswanathPolaki for your reply. After digging deeper I found this hook being used in function drupal_flush_all_caches. [function hook_flush_caches() {
  return array('cache_example');
}]. Can you help what this hook actually returns?

Comment: This hook returns an array of cache table names. Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_flush_caches/7.x for example cache_block is returned at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/block_flush_caches/7.x

Comment: What do you mean actually by "user based cache"? What kind of data is cached like that?